# move <div> to inside page

Tags: html, css

### Question

I am trying to create a loginForm dropdown on mouseover.  The form drops from the top left side of the miniLoginForm div which causes it to drop off the screen.  How do I get it to drop down from the top right side of the miniLoginForm div?

[image]

### HTML

```
    <li id="login"><?=anchor('users/login', 'Login')?>
        <div id="miniLoginForm">
            <?=form_open('users/login')?>
            <p>Username: <?=form_input('username')?></p>
            <p>Password: <?=form_password('password')?></p>
            <p><?=form_submit('Login', 'Login')?></p>
            <?=form_close()?>
            <p>New User? <?=anchor('users/register', 'Click here')?></p>
        </div>            
    </li>
```

### CSS

```
#miniLoginForm {
    margin: auto auto;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
}

nav {
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 6px 0 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to float your li element to the right (if you want the box and anchor on the right). Also, you need to set the relative position on it.

li element:

```
float: right;
position: relative;
```

box element

```
right: 0
```

Check this example to see how to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bnXbC/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you want to drop login form from top right corner of li having loggin class. Try following

.login
{
position: relative;
width : your width px;
}

miniLoginForm
{
position : absolute;
right : 0;
}